# GA Tracking Event in WordPress

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

I want to integrate GA Tracking Event on buttons in WordPress. Currently my theme is using ShortCodes and I can add specific .Class to it.

```
[vc_button text="Order Now" type="blue" align="left" url="#" size="big" class="ordernow"]
```

Google Analytic code is added on the site which is on Local Host and it's working. I found an article on this but don;t know what I'm missing.

```
http://www.gravitatedesign.com/blog/event-tracking-google-analytics-wordpress-edition/
```

There will be around 4 buttons of "Order Now" on a single page and I want to track their conversion rate with Google Analytic so I will know on which button visitors are getting engage. Hope this will deliver the exact thing that I want to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

please provide your result html of that buttons.

I usually use something like this

```
$('.ordernow').on('click', function(e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'order', document.URL);
});
```

you can add **additional** classes to track each button, example:

```
$('.ordernow button1').on('click', function(e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'order1', document.URL);
});
$('.ordernow button2').on('click', function(e) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'order2', document.URL);
});
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: I will test it and let you know what results I get.. Currently working on adding the CSS to the shortcode of the buttons.